# Decompress byte array using vb.net in .Net Compact Framework 2.0

Tags: vb.net

This is the first time I am working on compressing and decompressing data. I have a byte array(a dataset before compression) which is an already compressed data and I want to decompress it. But the decompression is to be done in .Net Compact framework 2.0 and this framework doesn't have System.IO.Compression library to use GZipStream or DeflateStream. Can anyone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried this but check this out:

http://www.aspecto-software.com/rw/applications/developer/compression/index.html